# How do I integrate Songbird with the desktop?

Tags: 11.10, notify-osd, default-programs, music-player, indicator-sound

I would like to know if I can have a better integration of Songbird into Unity and Gnome. Specifically, can Songbird:

- be controlled through the panel sound menu, like Banshee in Ubuntu 11.10?
- show notification bubbles when songs change?

I would rather use these features with Songbird. Although general suggestions on how to implement a better consolidation with Ubuntu are welcome!

Comment: Does any current Songbird user know how well the current builds are maintained?

Comment: Emmm the Songbird project has a fork: http://getnightingale.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.

1. Open *System Info* and select "Default Applications". Change the default music application to "Songbird".
2. Install the [ubuntu-notifier](http://addons.songbirdnest.com/addon/1672) addon.
3. Install the [MPRIS](http://addons.songbirdnest.com/addon/1626) addon.

**Be aware that Songbird no longer supports Ubuntu, and in turn, people developing Ubuntu integration have faded away.** I am not even sure if the addons listed above work anymore; if they do not, your only option is to code Ubuntu integration yourself.

As for the technical details for doing this (and these should become AskUbuntu questions in their own right):

- [This is how you register an music player in the sound menu.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoundMenu#Music_player_integration)
- [This is how you send pop-up messages.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/notify-send.1.html)

Comment: I installed MPRIS addon, but after it I don't understand what I should to do.

Comment: Relogin. If the plugin supports MPRIS2 properly (and Songbird is default) it should work with the Sound Menu.

Comment: Sorry, but what Songbird version admit this options?